# How to get JS event handler with URL in swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift3

class FeedBackFormViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler {

```
@IBOutlet weak var webViewShowing: UIView!

var formWebView: WKWebView!

private let fileString = UserSingleton.shared.feedbackFormLink

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupJSFile()
    formWebView.navigationDelegate = self
    previewFiles()
}

// show files in web view
private func previewFiles() {
    if let fileString = fileString, fileString != "" {
        let url = URL(string: fileString)
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
        UserSingleton.shared.showHUD()
        formWebView.load(myRequest)
    }else {
        Alerts.shared.show(alert: .error, message: "no file found", type: .error)
    }
}

private func setupJSFile() {
    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let js = "document.addEventListener('submit', function(){ window.webkit.messageHandlers.clickListener.postMessage('My hovercraft is full of eels!'); })"
    let script = WKUserScript(source: js, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: false)

    config.userContentController.addUserScript(script)
    config.userContentController.add(self, name: "submit")
    formWebView = WKWebView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds, configuration: config)
    webViewShowing.addSubview(formWebView)
}

func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {

    print(message.name)
    
}

@IBAction func dismissFeedbackFormVC(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

extension FeedBackFormViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!){
    
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState") { (result, error) in
        if let result = result {
            print(result)
        }
    }
}
```

}

only call wk navigation when the web view is loaded and I click anywhere no trigger call in userContentController any event

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to add this script for execution, just append it at the end of the `func setupJSFile`:
`formWebView.configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(script)`

also, you'd need to change your JS script to
`document.addEventListener('click', function(){ window.webkit.messageHandlers['iosListener'].postMessage('click clack!'); })`

Comment: func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {

        print(message.name)
        
    }
after successfull injuction JS webView.evaluateJavaScript called success but
above func not call when i. click in submit button

Comment: Because you didn't change your JS function to the correct one. Please read my answer carefully and compare it with your original question

Comment: let js = "document.addEventListener('submit', function(){ window.webkit.messageHandlers.clickListener.postMessage('My hovercraft is full of eels!'); })"

I am changing like this please check above code i already editd

Comment: your js string should look like `document.addEventListener('submit', function(){ window.webkit.messageHandlers['iosListener'].postMessage('My hovercraft is full of eels!'); })`